# Query & the_content() is showing in the header

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

This post is about two things:

1. All the results of this query are posting to the header of the Page *not* on the content area as they should. Do you know of a solution as to why this is happening and the simplest approach to resolve this?
2. Can you please critique my query? I want to know everything wrong with it (but is is working and producing the echoed results as expected)

   ```
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cv_testimonials_list');

   function cv_testimonials_list($query) {

   if ($query->is_page('9595') && $query->is_main_query()) {
       gravity_form(1, false, false, false, '', false);
       $args = array (
   'post_type'              => 'testimonial',
   'post_status'            => 'published',
   'pagination'             => true,
   'posts_per_page'         => '10',
   'order'                  => 'DESC',
   'orderby'                => 'date',);

   // The Query
   $query = new WP_Query( $args );
       while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                             echo "<p><strong>" . the_content() . "</strong></p>";

                             echo "<p>" . the_title() . "</p>";

                             echo "<p><a target='_blank' href='http://" . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonials-website-url',true) . "'>" . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonials-website-url', true ) . "</a></p>";

                           // print "<pre>";
                               // print_r($custom_fields);
                           // print "</pre>";
   endwhile;
   return;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: You are using [pre_get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) wrong. You are already in a query, so you don't need to run another one, but pass arguments to the current one, if conditions are met.

Answer (score 2):

The main query runs before the template is loaded. WordPress knows what template to load based on the results of that query.

If you want to insert an additional query into the content area, either create [a shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), or add a [filter on `the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) and do your page check/query output there.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I tried this suggestion: //add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cv_testimonials_list');

add_filter( 'the_content', 'cv_testimonials_list' ); But no dice. PHP error.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to give some guidance on properly adding the filter to my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

As Milo noted, you should just edit the query. Your problem is that you are then executing it and processing it while the pre_get_posts filter is processing.

Being a filter, pre_get_posts should be used to modify the query. It will then be ran and *then* your page will be displayed.

So:

```
function cv_testimonials_list($query) {

    if ($query->is_page('9595') && $query->is_main_query()) {
        gravity_form(1, false, false, false, '', false);
        $query->set('post_type', 'testimonial');
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');
        $query->set('orderby', 'date');
    }
}
```

That should edit the query as you want ... and your template should display the proper posts.

You might need to edit your template to use the logic you displayed in your while loop, but that part does not belong in the filter as the filter is run before the page is shown, which is why it is showing at the top of your page.

Comment: Privateer, thanks for posting this, but I tried this code in place of my existing, and I don't see why it would change anything, and same result - code is still outputting in the header.

Comment: I should add, the above code I am using is in a custom Plugin.

Comment: I'm not sure how your suggestion fits into my existing code, but thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

[pre_get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) is not a normal filter.

It's an action filter that happens after all arguments have been passed to any single query of your WordPress and before the queries are run against the db. All you  <del>can</del> should do inside `pre_get_posts()` is modify query parameters if WP conditionals are met (not all conditionals are available, just the ones that are known to WP before the query is run - read the docs for more details).

This is why you should not run another query inside `pre_get_posts()` (i'm surprised you don't get an infinite loop there) as your query should re-trigger pre_get_posts()), **nor should you print, echo, or return anything**.

Just modify *$query* if conditions are met.

This should answer both your questions.